# How do I connect to a server running in a Docker container?

Tags: macos, docker

I am running a Docker container on my computer. This container contains a Java application that starts a server listening on `http://localhost:9000`. When I run this code without Docker, it is trivial to connect to the server, but I am having some trouble connect when running inside a Docker container. My `docker run` command looks like this:

```
docker run -p 9000 -t -i my-image
```

The `NetworkSettings` output of `docker inspect` looks like this:

```
"NetworkSettings": {
    "Bridge": "",
    "SandboxID": "f9c77b7ae7804583fa60211b7d8cfeec5f154b29f9d174a4f0cdb5a8d6e41126",
    "HairpinMode": false,
    "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
    "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "Ports": {
        "9000/tcp": [
            {
                "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                "HostPort": "32768"
            }
        ]
    },
    "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/f9c77b7ae780",
    "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
    "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
    "EndpointID": "10b80d9de186be6ddf9e9d3bb1945124ec1fab7774a135720569e2bf4db3306e",
    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
    "Networks": {
        "bridge": {
            "EndpointID": "10b80d9de186be6ddf9e9d3bb1945124ec1fab7774a135720569e2bf4db3306e",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried connecting to `localhost:9000`, `localhost:32768`, `172.17.0.2:9000`, and `172.17.0.2:32768` to no avail. How can I connect to the server running in the Docker image?

Comment: Are you using docker directly on Linux? Or are you on Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are On OSX, that means you are using a VirtualBox VM for your docker environment.

Make sure you have [forwarded your port 9000](https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/blob/master/doc/WORKAROUNDS.md#port-forwarding) to your actual host (the mac), in order for that port to be visible from localhost.
This is valid for the old boot2docker, or the new docker machine.

```
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "tcp-port9000 ,tcp,,9000,,9000"
VBoxManage controlvm "boot2docker-vm" --natpf1 "udp-port9200 ,udp,,9000,,$9000
```

(`controlvm` if the VM is running, `modifyvm` is the VM is stopped)
(replace "`boot2docker-vm`" b ythe name of your vm: see `docker-machine ls`)
(use `-p 9000:9000` to depend on a static port mapping)

Comment: Hmm maybe I accepted too early. It doesn't seem that the server is getting any requests still.

Comment: @Max did you used `-p 9000:9000`?

Comment: Yea I did. I think the issue is with the tcp forwarding. How can I debug it?

Comment: @Max First make sure the tcp udp port is forwarded (open VirtualBox, and go to the Network settings of your VM)

Comment: Yes I am forwarding the ports. In the port forward section, the ports are specified but the guest and host IP boxes are blank. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: @Max the guest and host should be set to 9000.

Comment: The guest and host **ports** are set to 9000, but the guest and host **ip** boxes are blank.

Comment: @Max Ok, then you need to make sure the container is still running (`docker ls -a`), and if it is, you can exec a bash (`docker exec -it <container> bash`) to it and see what is going on.

Comment: I've done that. When I'm in the container I can successfully reach the host. Something weird must be going on with the port forwarding.

Comment: @Max no value on host should mean broadcast, but just for testing, try with 127.0.0.1, as in http://xomino.com/2015/05/06/setting-port-forwarding-for-boot2docker-to-access-the-internet/ or http://odewahn.github.io/docker-jumpstart/boot2docker.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to access your container from the VirtualBox host environment.
Run the container with `-p 9000:9000` option:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -t -i my-image
```

Then run docker-machine to find out IP of docker host:

```
docker-machine ip default
```

And then access your Java application from the output of command above. For example if it is 192.168.99.100:

http://192.168.99.100:9000