# How do you connect your app to a running Docker container?

Tags: docker

Suppose I have a Spring Boot app with a Spring Data starter

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Suppose I want it to connect to a running Postgres container (here's the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)). My naive approach to simply use `localhost` failed (even though I successfully connected to a Eureka server container through `localhost`)

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    username: ${POSTGRES_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:postgres}
    url: ${POSTGRES_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres}
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
```

I figure it's because I need to know the host, the IP address. I checked the Postgres logs:

```
2024-02-21 22:57:26 2024-02-21 19:57:26.287 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
```

Is this the host I need? I tried to change the port in the URL to `0.0.0.0`, but I still got the same `ConnectionException`

I know Docker has some DNS resolvers for images bundled in a `docker-compose` file so I can use service names instead of actual IP addresses. But what if I don't want to bundle the services?

**So, how do I connect?** Which, I figure, boils down to "How do I get to know a real container port, not a phony one in the logs?"

I realize that it sounds a lot like something already asked here on SO ages ago. But believe it or not, I actually examined every single suggested question (under the label "Do any of these answers answer your question?"), but none of them appeared helpful

In particular, I tried following [this advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33658347/23434786) and executed

```
docker run -p 5432:5432 --name postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -t -i postgres
```

It didn't lead me anywhere. I couldn't execute any `docker-machine` command after that

Comment: You need to `docker network create` a network both containers can run on; `docker run --net` both containers on that network; and use `docker run -e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=...` to point Spring at the other container, using the container's name as the host name in the URL.